# SQL change "like" to "contains"

Tags: sql

```
products table (mySQL)

record_id     categories (comma-delimited list)
---------     --------------------------------
1             960|1,957|1,958|1
```

I have the following dynamic query (simplified for the purposes of this question). The query is passed specified categories, each in the format xxxx|yyyy, and I need to return  products having the passed category in its comma-delimited list of categories.

The current query looks like:

```
select p.* from products p
where (p.categories like '%27|0%' or p.categories like '%972|1%' or p.categories like '%969|1%')
```

But, the LIKE clause sometimes permits anomalies.
I would like to write the query more like:

```
select p.* from products p 
where (p.categories contains '27|0' or p.categories contains'972|1' or p.categories contains  '969|1')
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "the LIKE clause sometimes permits anomalies" can you give an example?

Comment: If a particular categories column contains "1766|2" and my query is "select * from products where categories like '%766|2%', it will pick it up when I don't want it to.

Comment: Well yeah, because `1766|2` matches the pattern `%766|2%`...

Comment: Are you open to changing the schema and adding a ProductCategories junction table? Putting it into first normal form will make this type of query easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function:

```
select p.* from products p 
where (LOCATE('27|0', p.categories) > 0 or LOCATE('972|1', p.categories) > 0 or LOCATE('969|1', p.categories) > 0))
```

EDIT: If you want to avoid false positives, you could double the amount of conditions, or triple if second number can be first number of anouther category:

```
select p.* from products p 
where (
  LOCATE('27|0', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',27|0', p.categories) > 0 or 
  LOCATE('972|1', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',972|1', p.categories) > 0 or
  LOCATE('969|1', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',969|1', p.categories) > 0
)
```

EDIT2: Final solution (long, after knowing that commas are separators):

```
select p.* from products p 
where (
  p.categories = '27|0' OR LOCATE('27|0,', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',27|0,', p.categories) > 0 or LOCATE(',27|0', p.categories) = CHAR_LENGTH(p.categories) - CHAR_LENGTH(',27|0') + 1 or
  p.categories = '972|1' OR LOCATE('972|1,', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',972|1,', p.categories) > 0 or LOCATE(',972|1', p.categories) = CHAR_LENGTH(p.categories) - CHAR_LENGTH(',972|1') + 1 or
  p.categories = '969|1' OR LOCATE('969|1,', p.categories) = 1 or LOCATE(',969|1,', p.categories) > 0 or LOCATE(',969|1', p.categories) = CHAR_LENGTH(p.categories) - CHAR_LENGTH(',969|1') + 1
)
```

Alternative (shorter, using REGEX, possibly slower)

```
select p.* from products p WHERE
  p.categories REGEXP '(,|^)27\|0(,|$)'
  or p.categories REGEXP '(,|^)972\|1(,|$)'
  or p.categories REGEXP '(,|^)969\|1(,|$)'
```

You will need to escape | characters for REGEXP as this is a special character in regular expressions.

EDIT3:

REGEXP solution could be improved by using just one regular expression, such expressions are compiled during querying so single compilation is faster than 3 separate compilations even if matching expression is more complicated:

```
select p.* from products p WHERE p.categories REGEXP '(,|^)(27\|0|972\|1|969\|1)(,|$)'
```

Comment: I just tried it; it seems to produce the same results as my LIKE query, i.e. still returning unwanted records.

Comment: Thanks, the edit got me thinking. I resolved it by recognising the comma-delimiting: 
LOCATE(',27|0,', p.categories). 
BUT this is going to be a problem for first and last items in the comma-delimited list, i.e. the first item doesn't have a leading comma and the last item doesn't have a trailing comma.

Comment: thats what you get using non atomic values! 1NF